# Rails run AND query in where clause with joins

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Currently I have the following query

```
Policy.joins(policy_coverages: :cpt_code).where(policy_coverages: { cpt_codes: { code: code_array } })
```

This query is returning all policies which has a policy coverage having one of the cpt_codes in the array. It is performing an `OR` query.

How can I write a query that returns only the policies which have policy_coverages with all the cpt_codes in the array `code_array`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group the records and use having to set a condition on each group (each policy):

```
Policy.group(:id)
      .joins(policy_coverages: :cpt_code)
      .where(policy_coverages: { cpt_codes: { code: code_array } })
      .having(CptCode.arel_table[Arel.star].count.gteq(code_array.length))
```

Use `.eq` instead of `.gteq` if you want to match records with just those policies codes and no others.

Comment: max - it is giving me a syntax error
`Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*) >= 1 LIMIT 11' at line 1`

Comment: Does using `CptCode.arel_table[:id]` solve the issue? I don't have MySQL installed but I know that sqlite doesn't like `COUNT(tablename.*)` either.

Comment: Yes that does solve the issue. Thankyou Max